# Apache Beam Version 2.2.0

Tags: release, apache-beam

I'm currently using apache beam version 2.1.0 but there is a bug that, fortunatly, has been fixed in the new version. According to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/versions/12341044), it seems that version 2.2.0 is ready but the release date has not yet been published. Does anyone know when it can happen?

Comment: You would need to contact the developers of apache beam. They can be contacted on the dev mailing list found here: https://beam.apache.org/get-started/support/ or on the slack group.

Comment: Released on Dec 1st. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Pull Apache beam 2.2.0 Stable Version (Not SnapShot ) From GitHub the link is -: https://github.com/apache/beam/releases/tag/v2.2.0-RC3

Answer (score 2):

Apache Beam 2.2.0 is now available as of [2017-12-01](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/versions/12341044)!

**Google Cloud Dataflow** team is also working on releasing the matching Dataflow release.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no one knows. They are busy voting on it on the dev mailing list:
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/da2acabdb15c9f8d11351f9167633a4b089664fe3cce014ba619c937@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E

Most probably very soon.